# Best way to retrieve Firebase NoSQL/JSON data?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm storing data in several nodes in my Google Firebase Database and image paths from my Google Firebase Storage.

Up until now, my application would for example retrieve specific data like an ID from a 'user' node and combine it into an array with specific data from a 'friendships' node, and an image path retrieved from storage. These are all promises and impact the performance of my app.

I'm not very familiar with NoSQL/JSON and I'm starting to believe I'm tackling the problem the wrong way. Can anyone confirm my idea that the best way to go about this situation would be to store the data I need to retrieve from the 'user' table into the friendships table for easier retrieval, including a link to for my image so I don't have to handle these promises either? That way I could simply retrieve a node and get all the data I need instantly. It means some data duplication is present in my database, but after reading up on it, it seems that this is normal for a NoSQL database. I hope someone can inform me if this is the right way to approach this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the below link very helpful when I a similar problem. Check out the 'Data Modeling in Firebase' section - more specific to Angular, but data modelling applies to all.

http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-firebase/

It goes through potential wrong and right ways to approach the data modeling. Taking into consideration performance of a NoSQL large JSON object.

Hope it helps.